# jquery append row onclick

Tags: jquery, append, row

**EDIT --- Trying an even more simplified version.... Still doesn't work... Returns $(this).closest is not a function error... **

```
$("#fitable input[name^=f1]").focus(function() {
        var newRow = '<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>';
        $(this).closest("tbody").append(newRow);
    });
```

**Original Post**

Pretty new to jQuery, so I'm hoping someone can help me out...  There's a couple of things going on here... Help with any part of it is appreciated.

For starters, I'm trying to append a row to a table when a user clicks in the first enabled input field for that row.   Here's the code I'm trying to use:

```
    $("#fitable > tbody > tr > td > input").bind('focus', function() {
        if($(this).attr('disabled', false)) {
            $(this).click(function() {
                    var newRow = '<tr><td><input name="f1[]" value="" /><label>CustNew</label></td><td><input name="field_n1[]" value="" /><label>N1</label></td><td><input name="field_n2[]" value="" /><label>N2</label></td></tr>';
                    $(this).closest("tbody").append(newRow);
            });
        }
    });
```

If it's helpful, here's the html:

```
<table id="fitable">
    <tbody>
        <tr valign="top">
            <td><input disabled="disabled" name="cust" id="edit-cust" value="sample@sample.com" type="text"><label>Cust</label></td>
            <td><input name="field_n1[]" value="" type="text"><label>N1</label></td>
            <td><input name="field_n2[]" value="" type="text"><label>N2</label></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: try to replace closets with parents

Comment: or `$(this).parents("tbody:first").append(newRow);`

Comment: What @[Jim Schubert] said too!

Comment: Growl... Neither worked.  No errors, and no appending.  Do I need to go through the whole parent().parent()... rigamarole?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your selector is incorrect.  Try this:

```
$("#fitable > tr td input:enabled:first").focus(function() {
    var newRow = '<tr><td><input name="f1[]" value="" /><label>CustNew</label></td><td><input name="field_n1[]" value="" /><label>N1</label></td><td><input name="field_n2[]" value="" /><label>N2</label></td></tr>';
    $(this).parents("tbody:first").append(newRow);
});
```

You don't have to check disabled in the handler function, because this will only bind to the enabled elements in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

I think your if statement is setting the clicked attribute to false. Try this:

```
if( $( this ).attr( 'disabled' ) == false ) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I tried that, unfortunately, same behavior... as in no appending happening... Do you see anything else it could be?

Comment: in the if statement, add console.log( 'if' ); or something.. just to test you're actually getting into that statement. Then open your console and check for the log. Or, if you don't want to use the console, do alert( 'if' ); in place of console.log... let us know what happens

Comment: alert('if') pops up, so I know I'm in the right place...  I altered my code to make it even more simple, and it's still not appending... Going to edit my original post in just a sec so you can see the latest revision...

Comment: Try wrapping your append var: $( [your stuff] )

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#fitable input").focus(function() {
        if($(this).attr('disabled', false)) {
            $(this).click(function() {
                    var newRow = '<tr><td><input name="f1[]" value="" /><label>CustNew</label></td><td><input name="field_n1[]" value="" /><label>N1</label></td><td><input name="field_n2[]" value="" /><label>N2</label></td></tr>';
                    $(this).closest("tbody").append(newRow);
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: Trying this returns an error: $(this).closest is not a function... (?)